# Matlab replace axis range

Tags: matlab, plot

I have x axis from 0 to 96 where every number stands for quarter of hour in a day(96/4 = 24 hours). I need the axis to show the hours 0 to 24 isn't there a way to modify only the axis after the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
>> set(gca, 'XTick', 0:4:96);
>> set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:24);
```

For example:

```
>> plot(0:96,0:96)
>> set(gca, 'XTick', 0:4:96);
>> set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:24);
```

Resultant figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. A good one might be to change the x-data of the plot:

```
%# get handles of plot objects
chH = get(gca,'children');
%# for each child: divide the x-data by 4 and put it back
if length(chH) == 1
   set(chH,'xdata',get(chH,'xdata')/4);
else
   set(chH,{'xdata'},cellfun(@(x)x/4,get(chH,'xdata'),'uni',0));
end
xlim([0 24])
```

This reads the x-data of the objects plotted into the current axes, divides it by 4, and puts it back. Then you change the axes limits to 0...24

Comment: The name 'xdata' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.
This is what I get what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The name 'xdata' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.
I get this where is the problem?

Comment: @totpiko: I have fixed my mistake. I have also expanded the solution so that it'll work if there are multiple objects plotted into the axes. The advantage of this solution is that it'll allow you to zoom and to plot additional data (with correct x-values).