# How to scale ms to seconds in matlab plot?

Tags: matlab

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500400/matlab-replace-axis-range) question, however it does not seem to work for me (the example in the question does)

Here is my plot:

[image]

The length of the x axis array is 1734. The values go from 0 to 1299000 (time in milliseconds). I would like to make the time (x-axis) be in seconds or minutes.

How do I do it?

Comment: I guess the simplest would be to divide the x-values by 1000 or 60000.

Comment: @RobertP. Wow, sometimes I feel so silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is by dividing the `x`-values by 1000 (to get seconds) or 60000 (to get minutes).

```
x = linspace(0,1299000,1734);
t = sin(x/30000);
plot(x/60000,t)
```

[image]